# updating existing custom field in JIRA with python

Tags: python, jira

Im trying to update an existing custom field within python so that I can automatically add several "values" that can be used in a dropdown box.  The below line targets the custom field I want

```
for a in jira.fields():
    if a['name'] == "block":
        #print a.update(fields={'customfield_12100': {'value': "testingtest"}})
        print a
```

I know this because it returns the correct fields:

```
{u'name': u'block', u'searchable': True, u'navigable': True, u'custom': True, u'clauseNames': [u'cf[12100]', u'Lease Block'], u'orderable': True, u'id': u'customfield_12100', u'schema': {u'customId': 12100, u'type': u'option', u'custom': u'com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select'}}
```

But The new value is not added to my list of custom field options.  How do you go about adding the value?

Jira Version 7.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not be done with the OOB Jira install.  A third party plugin must be installed https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jiracustomfieldeditorplugin/server/overview.